# How to store the needles found in a haystack into an array?

Tags: php

I have a few unknown needles in a haystack, of which I want all the needles extracted and stored in an array. The unknown needles are all in the same format. They start with a [, followed by 1 to 10 digits and end with a ].

So far i have this:

```
$keywords = preg_split("/\[[0-9]{1,10}\]/i", $string);
```

However, this splits it up by the needles I actually want to keep. Is there a way to reverse this search by discarding everything except the needles and store every needle in an array?

Comment: Are you looking for `preg_match`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) - the needles found in the string will be returned as part of an array.

[example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bpc-arq)

```
preg_match_all('/\[[0-9]{1,10}\]/i', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking at different functions and combinations for the past 3 hours, but completely overlooked preg_match_all().